# Power series expansion with coefficient explanation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

So I'm doing power series expansion and I have this example in my notes to walk through the steps of solving a differential equation using power series. So I was just wondering if someone could explain to me.

[image]

What I'm confused about is on the second line, the second part, that was multiplied by the coefficient "3", when the summation is changed from n=1 to n=0, you sub in n+1 for all the n's, but why, for the first part that was multiplied by the x coefficient, on the third line when the first summation is changed from n=1 to n=0, why does that not require n+1 to be subbed into all n's?

I pretty much know how to do all the other steps, but I keep getting the wrong answer on my questions and I'm guessing it's because I don't know the rules around how to change the Ns

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first case is a change of variables. Let $n'= n-1$ (and therefore $n = n'+1$). We have
$$-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} 3 n a_n x^{n-1} = -\sum\limits_{n'+1=1}^{\infty} 3 (n'+1) a_{n'+1} x^{n'+1-1} = -\sum\limits_{n'=0}^{\infty} 3 (n'+1) a_{n'+1} x^{n'}$$

But we usually do not change the name of the variable each time we make such a change. So we still write $n$ instead of $n'$.

The second case, however, is not a change of variables. Notice that for $n = 0$, we have $n a_n x^n = 0 \cdot a_0 x^0 = 0$. So
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n a_n x^n = 0 \cdot a_0 x^0 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n a_n x^n = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty n a_n x^n$$

Comment: so how do you know if it's a change of variables or not? because I still don't see a difference between the two summations

Comment: As you noticed, in the first case, all $n$ were substitued by $n+1$. This is a hint of a change of variables.

Comment: yeah but how do I know if I'm supposed to sub in n+1 or not? since this is just an example I'll have to do it myself in the future, like I have to change all the n=1 summations to n=0, so when I'm changing it how am I supposed to tell if one summation is supposed to undergo variable change? because it seems like you could variable change for both of these if you wanted to, I just don't really know how you can tell

Comment: In order to regroup everything in the end, you need two things : the exponent of $x$ must be the same in every sums, and the sums must have the same range. In the first case, the exponent of $x$ was $n-1$, so a change of variables was needed so it become $n$. The range was adjusted at the same time. In the second case, the exponent of $x$ was already $n$, so we did not want to change it. Therefore, we adjusted the range of the sum by making appear the missing term.